# maximum call stack size exceeded mongoose at version 5

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Currently I am using mongoose 4.9.9 with node and its working fine,
I want to upgrade to latest 5 when I install latest and run project it giving me error

> maximum call stack size exceeded : rang error

when I set back to version 4.9.9 it again run perfectly.
does anyone know this?
thanks in advance

Comment: You get this error after which request?

Comment: on get request when mongoose find query executes

Comment: You should insert the schema you use and the request. Maybe there is something special about it.

Comment: but its working fine in version 4.9.9, its giving me issue only in version 5.x

Comment: maybe because mongoose changed something about an option or the request you use